# Разница между ArrayDeque и LinkedList

Tags: java

В чем между ними разница с точки зрения реализации?

Comment: Есть подозрения, что тут можно провести аналогию с плюсовыми ```std::list``` и ```std::deque```,
то бишь в первом каждому элементу соответствуют два указателя: вперед и назад, а второй состоит как бы из блоков (массивов) связанных с другими.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue vs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type)

Comment: @dIm0n класс LInkedList тоже реализует интерфейс Deque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разница в том, что в основе ArrayDeque лежит массив указателей.
В то время как, LinkedList это набор элементов, каждый из которых содержит указатель на следующий.